# get rowIndex in rowEdit ajax event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have an editable dataTable (row edit mode). When I edit row and click tick to confirm new value, I would like to validate some columns (some of them are required) using jqxvalidator. So, when a tick is clicked, `validateRule(#{rowIndex});` function should validate the row which was just edited, but `rowIndex` value passed to this function is `undefined`.

Is there any other way to get row index and pass it to JavaScript function?

Some of my xhtml code:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblRule" var="item" value="#{bean.ruleList}" binding="#{bean.dtRules}" editable="true"
    editMode="row" rowIndexVar="rowIndex" widgetVar="tblRuleWidget">
    <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{bean.doEdit}" update="tblRule" onstart="validateRule(#{rowIndex}); " />
    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" onstart="hideValidatorMsg();" />

    <p:column>
        <p:rowEditor />
    </p:column>
    <p:column id="colRuleId" headerText="Id" >
        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column id="colRuleCode" headerText="Code">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{item.code}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText id="inRuleCode" value="#{item.code}" onblur="hideValidatorMsg(); validateRule(#{rowIndex});" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

JavaScript:

```
function validateRule(rowIdx) {
    var namespace = 'view' + $('[id$=hidNamespace]').val();

    $('#' + namespace + '\\:form1').jqxValidator({
        animation : 'none',
        scroll : false,
        arrow : false,
        rules : [ {
            input : '#' + namespace + '\\:form1\\:tabView\\:tblRule\\:' + rowIdx + '\\:inRuleCode',
            message : 'Required field!',
            action : 'blur',
            position : 'top',
            rule : 'required'
        } ]
    });

    if ($('#' + namespace + '\\:form1').jqxValidator('validateInput', '#' + namespace + '\\:form1\\:tabView\\:tblRule\\:' + rowIdx + '\\:inRuleCode') === false) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your previous approach you won't get the `rowIndex`, the ajax event is registered once, so the `rowIndex` won't be passed as if it's a loop or an actionListener of a button for each row !

**For PrimeFaces 5.2 and <**

The `rowIndex`is stored in the row as a data, the dataTable depends quite enough on this methodology.

That said, and based on the source code of the Widget, here's how to get the triggerer index:

```javascript
PF('dataTableWV').getRowMeta($(event.target).closest('tr')).index
```

Basicly the `event.target` is the ✓ icon, the closest `tr` would be the row, passing this row to [`getRowMeta`](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/b2c095571eb81ac9ff6dd3180630e7f6c4fad115/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/datatable/datatable.js#L2088) function would extract the data attributes, one of them is the `index`.

**Starting from PrimeFaces 5.3:**

The `rowIndex` can be found in the params of the extension of the ajax behaviour.

```
ext.params[0].value
```

---

*- **Note**: that should be passed in `onstart` of the ajax event (as in the question).*

Comment: I've been using `event` in `onstart` but after I upgraded to PrimeFaces 5.3 `event` is undefined. Any ideas?

Comment: @PanuHaaramo you are correct, I have updated the answer.

Comment: I don´t know why but the **ext** was not accessible from my JS callback scope. The solution was to get it from **cfg** Object like so:
`cfg.ext.params[0].value`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can take this approach :-

```
<p:dataTable binding="#{YourValue}" and so on ...>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandButton ... onclick="return getMyRowIndex(#{YourValue.rowIndex})" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Using `onstart="validateRule(#{bean.dtRules.rowIndex}); "` gives `rowIndex` value of -1.